# rsyslog big data 44 terabytes of storage yearly on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, rsyslog

I have tried rsyslog Remote for Mikrotik user log tcp and udp
Everything was working very well
But there are some problems that I need to attend

1. If the size of the log is up to 120 GB daily, I need about 44 terabytes of storage yearly.
   2 - file size 1 GB needs a lot to open it on Windows so how much larger.
2. It will take a lot of time to search for a specific recording.
3. If you need to find a specific customer on a given day, it will take a lot of time to extract>

Is there a script for example to divide the file into several files, and each month will have a file and within it days and idle hours
Every hour it changes the place of preservation to facilitate the process of research and reading.

Or is there a program ready to do all this

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLD9L.png][1]
this record in 10 minutes

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbtGk.png][1]
this nice record all user log

Comment: That is a huge log file. Are you sure you want to keep all of it for a year?

Comment: yes i need keep all of it for a year

Comment: The usual procedure is to activate `logrotate` on a large log file so that it is divided into daily (or weekly, etc.) files, each neatly labeled with the date, and zipped if desired. Did you look into `logrotate`, or doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: I want to divide it but do not know how to do it
And if you put hdd Raid 0 will not hurt anything